# Scaffolding breaks when I move my DbContextClass to Data Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, data-layers, t4scaffolding

I have my DbContext class in the same folder and namespace as my Models (`MvcApplication.Models`). I thought it would be better to put it in the folder and namespace where my repositories are (`MvcApplication.Data`). I did that, the code compiles and runs, but then I tried to scaffold a controller. I got this error:

`Exception calling "GetDirectoryName" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."
At C::\....\MvcScaffolding.1.0.9\tools\Controller\MvcScaffolding.Controller.ps1:89 char:122`

This is line 89:
`$controllerNamespace = [T4Scaffolding.Namespaces]::Normalize($defaultNamespace + "." + [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($outputPath).Replace([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar, "."))`

So I moved it back and the scaffolder works again. Can I fix the scaffolder to let me move the DbContext?

Maybe the data layer is the wrong place for it anyway? I put some custom sql in the SaveChanges override but maybe that was breaking an unwritten rule. Maybe the sql should move and the DbContext should stay with the Models?

Comment: Have you gone to line 89 char 122 on file MvcScaffolding.Controller.ps1?

Comment: Its the call to `GetDirectoryName`. Something wrong with what's in `$outputPath`

Comment: There's a line that sets it `$outputPath = Join-Path Controllers $ControllerName` but "Controllers" comes from nowhere I can see. Don't know anything about programming or debugging T4 templates I'm afraid